Installing Linux, which partition to keep incase returning to Windows?
I am installing Linux on my old PC. I want to wipe everything including all the data and the windows 10 OS, however I don't want to wipe the partition that has the files/data to reinstall windows 10 on the PC, just in case I decide to return to windows in the future or if I give the PC to someone who wants to use windows. I know how to install Linux and all that, I just want to make sure I can identify the partition(s) so I can make sure it is not deleted during the installation of Linux. Which partition(s) should I keep to accomplish this?
More info 1
I want Windows removed and deleted to free up as much space as possible. I just don't want to remove the last possible way I can reinstall Windows 10, since it will be unsupported soon. If I wipe everything and decide I want to come back, I want to be able to boot/install it via BIOS options. I think this may be the 100 MB Disk 0, partition 2, with status of EFI System Partition. There are also 2 other partitions on Disk 0: partition 1 which is 499MB status of Recovery Partition and partition 5 which is 576MB also status of Recovery Partition. In the BIOS boot manager under Boot Options #1 is says "Windows Boot Manager (P0: SanDisk SD8SN8U128G1002)".
More info 2
I want to install Linux but keep a backup copy of windows installation (on the system itself) if things go wrong or if I decide to change back in the future. I don't want a recovery USB and have to remember what it's for, I'd much rather have a system partition. I am finding many related answers but they all seem to go off in a different direction. I just want to keep 1 maybe 2 partitions so that if I want to, I can go into my BIOS, change the boot orders, and start with the windows installation.
At this point I am resetting the PC and wiping all data, reinstalling windows from local file. If things look the same after, I am leaning towards keeping partition 2 and 5. I am not doing dual boot. Any help is appreciated. Here's a screenshot of Disk Manager. Partition 1 has an offset of 1024 KB, while partition 5 has on offset of 118 GB.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

There no such partition. As with ANY desktop OS, Windows is installed by booting installation media, typically an USB stick. Make sure to download the Windows 10 ISO before it becomes unavailable (expected no later then October 2025).

You'll be able to reinstall Windows using a download from Microsoft, burned to a USB using any other Windows computer. I think there's questions on this site about creating those install drives using other OS as well.

Yea, your computer has the Recovery partition, but that's too small to contain anything more than repair information. It does not contain a full install/recovery image. Some computer brands, in the past (more than 10 years ago) had custom recovery partitions, but with improvements to Windows' deployment capabilities these are unnecessary and so have been mostly dropped.

@music2myear - that makes sense. so that means I have an OEM copy of windows and that's why i have a recovery partition on the internal drive. i just don't get why theres 2. it made me think that the larger one was 1 I created myself before I stopped using the pc.

With those improvements in distribution, there's not really any such thing as an "OEM version" of Windows. OEM customizations can be configured through agreements with Microsoft associated with the license assigned to your computer and stored in your system firmware. So, no OEM image, no license key, just a computer with identifiers known to the OEM and Microsoft.

so the recovery partions only have some windows files that are needed incase i reset and do a system recovery. and the EFI System Partition is a layer that helps do this. but since none of these help in installing windows from scratch, and i would still need a windows 10 iso, it would then be perfectly fine to also delete the EFI System Partition, correct? the windows iso on the usb would take care of this (reinstalling the EFI System or equivalent)? so basically i don't have to worry about deleting something that will brick my PC due to erasing software that can interpret installation files.

The EFI partition is where the bootloaders are saved and read from, not a "layer". Yes, if you intend to reinstall only Windows later to give or sell it, it's in your best interest to start from scratch. Some people will even recommend more drastic measures but, personal opinion, that's overkill in 99% of the cases. Just delete all partitions - it can be done from the installer easily - then tell it to install in that drive and it automatically will create all the required partitions.

OK thx. Yea I'm not well versed in operating system lingo and how it all works. I've read similar sounding things from my research but never a direct answer to these questions. Thank you everybody!
